# What does a backslash mean when used in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Question About RegExp Object in Javascript and I did not understand why print that output

What this Code Actually mean

```
/\[^xyz]/g
/\[0-9]/g
```

Why I Put BackSlash after the Slash , That is the question
Because in every example the code written like that
I mean what is the different from this code

```
/[^xyz]/g
/[0-9]/g
```

I just Want in which way must write..

Comment: `[` is special in regular expressions - it signifies a character class, and is ended by a respective `]`. Using a backslash will escape it and make it part of the regular expression to be matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `[..]` has a special meaing in regular expression. `[xyz]` matches `x`, `y` or `z`.
`[^...]` negate thats; `[^xyz]` matches any character that is not `x`, `y`, nor `z`.

But if `[` is preceded by `\`, it loses its special meaning and matches `[` literally.